# How to update component's state after redirect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a component that renders a page which includes a dropdown menu. When the user selects an option on the menu, I want him to be redirected to the selected page.

The code below works, meaning that the user is in fact redirected, but as soon as the new page is rendered I get the following error:

> Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on.

Here's my component:

```
class UserPage extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {

        super( props ); 

        this.state = {
            selectValue: this.props.match.params.slug, 
            redirect: false
        }

    }

    handleSelectChange( event ) {
        this.setState({
            selectValue: event.target.value, 
            redirect: true
        }); 
    }

    render() {

        const redirect = this.state.redirect; 

        if( redirect ) {
            return <Redirect to={ "/you/" + this.state.selectValue } />; 
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <PageHeader 
                    currentPageSlug={ this.state.currentPageSlug }
                    selectIntro="You're viewing"
                    selectOptions={ this.props.menus.userMenu }
                    selectDefault={ this.state.value } 
                    onSelectChange={ this.handleSelectChange.bind( this ) } />
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I believe the problem is that the state in `constructor` doesn't update when the component re-renders, so `redirect` still evaluates to true and the app tries to redirect again.

So the question is: how do I set `redirect` to `false` once the component re-rendered? I tried updating the state in methods like `componentDidMount`, `componentWillMount`, etc. but they all produce errors of their own...

Comment: Have you tried componentDidUpdate?

Comment: Yes, didn't work!

Comment: Should ```this.state.value``` have a value anywhere, it doesn't seem to have any value assigned to it from this snippet. Should it be ```this.state.selectValue```?

Comment: That's a typo, sorry. Should be `this.state.selectValue`, which is set in the `constructor`. But like I said, the problem is with `redirect` evaluating to true when the component re-renders.

Comment: Is the componentDidUpdate error an infinite loop error?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the current route and where are you trying to re-direct?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the current route and where are you trying to re-direct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could also work if you're using an older version of react:

```
componentDidUpdate () {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
        this.setState({
            redirect: false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! But what do you mean older version of react? Is this going to be deprecated?

Comment: ```componentDidUpdate``` isn't going to be depreacted yet. It's that ```getDerivedStateFromProps``` is a very new lifecycle method and may not be in your version of React that you have installed.

Answer (score 3):

There is a static method in life cycle called `getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)`, I used to `componentWillReceiveProps()` in old time, but it will be deprecated, you can have more information in [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

In your case, It seems UserPage is like a template and taking `this.props.match.params.slug` as parameter to render different content. The problem here is when this component be mounted, React only check difference  to re-render it but not re-mount it, you need `getDerivedStateFromProps()` to detect the new props coming and set new state.

```
class UserPage extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {

        super( props ); 

    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)
        // Below won't work in this method.
        // this.setState({
        //   selectValue: nextProps.match.params.slug, 
        //   redirect: false
        //  });
        //
        // We need to return the new state object directly
        return {
          selectValue: nextProps.match.params.slug, 
          redirect: false
        }
    }

    handleSelectChange( event ) {
        this.setState({
            selectValue: event.target.value, 
            redirect: true
        }); 
    }

    render() {

        const redirect = this.state.redirect; 

        if( redirect ) {
            return <Redirect to={ "/you/" + this.state.selectValue } />; 
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <PageHeader 
                    currentPageSlug={ this.state.currentPageSlug }
                    selectIntro="You're viewing"
                    selectOptions={ this.props.menus.userMenu }
                    selectDefault={ this.state.value } 
                    onSelectChange={ this.handleSelectChange.bind( this ) } />
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not working for me. It seems like `getDerivedStateFromProps`doesn't even get called: if I add a `console.log`inside the method nothing is printed to the console...

Comment: @grazianodev, Sorry that I missed `static` in the front of function in my old answer and I've updated it.

Comment: I had already tried with `static`, still not logging anything!

Comment: @grazianodev, sorry that could be just like @gillyhl said, it's not in your version, replace it with `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` may work, or just use gillyhl's, that is just good.

Comment: And maybe you would be interested in what's the difference between them: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating